# Accessing public static java method from scala

Tags: scala, playframework-2.0

I'm trying to use the Java facebook library here http://restfb.com/#publishing in a scala play2 app, but when trying to call the static `with` methods below, it gives me "Compliation Error [identifier expected but 'with' found.]".

```
val fbClass = classOf[FacebookType]
val param = Parameter.with("message", msg)
val attachment = BinaryAttachment.with("cat.png", stream)
val fbResp = facebookClient.publish("me/photos", fbClass, attachment, param)
```

I see that there is an issue trying to invoke *protected* static methods, but these are defined as public, as can be seen in the [javadocs](http://restfb.com/javadoc/index.html) and the [source](https://github.com/revetkn/restfb/blob/master/source/library/com/restfb/BinaryAttachment.java).  Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`with` is a keyword in Scala, for example, used in mixin multiple traits.

```
class A extends B with C with D
```

So if a method is named `with` in Java library, you need surround it with `` (backtick) when you calling it:

```
BinaryAttachment.`with`("cat.png", stream)
```